# Searching a file name in file using SHELL SCRIPT

Tags: shell

I will fetch the file names from the file say: FILE_A, and will search these file names in another file say: File_B Using the script say: script.sh

I want to print those file names which are not present in a file say: FILE_B.
I use the code but it didn't work.

Code in the script->script.sh is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line

do
       grep -v "$line" FILE_B

done<FILE_A
```

please help me. why it is not working and what is the solution of it?

Comment: very inefficient to grep file_b for every line in file_a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No extra linefeed between `while` and `do`
2. `grep -v expr file` will
       print all lines of those files, not containing `expr`. What you want, is just the result whether it's found or not. You need to test the
   exit state.

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
       grep -q "$line" FILE_B || echo "$line"

done<FILE_A
```

grep returns exit 0 if a line was found. The || concatenation with echo means: `execute echo when exit state != 0`- i.e. when `$line` was not found.

Comment: grep should also add -w parameter to check full file names instead of just blind text searching...right?

Comment: TBD: what, if filename is only part of the line? OP does not post any requirements about these details.

Comment: no, let say if the filename in file_A is file123 and there is a file "file12345" in file_B then to handle such cases, -w is required

Comment: still TBD: could also be `-x`- hole line. Unclear

Comment: I WANT PRINT ALL LINE of those files, not containing expr

Comment: your answer is correct as i needed but i didn't understood why -v didn't work as if i tried it normally it works, why not in the loop of script, please reply

Answer (score 2):

`grep` can read its input from a file; no need for a loop.

```
grep -Fxvf FILE_A FILE_B
```

The `-F` option specifies that the input is literal strings, not regular expressions. Otherwise an input which contains regex metacharacters would not match itself; or not only itself. For example, the regular expression `a.c` matches "aac", "abc", etc.

The `-x` option requires a full-line match. Otherwise, the input "bc" would match on any line containing it as a substring, such as "abcd".

The `-v` option says to print non-matching lines instead of matching.

Finally, the lowercase `-f` option specifies a file name as its argument to use as input for the patterns to match.

Comment: It is not giving the output though the command is running, your answer need some more addition/modification to print it. Please reply.

Comment: I can reply but not really help without more information.  It works for me. http://pastebin.com/9y2YvwEN

Comment: but it is not working in my environment, the sample u shown over pastebin(link mention in the reply), i need it be working as similar. if u know why it is not working then please share the information.

Comment: I'll write this slowly: If you don't provide additional information, we can only guess.  DOS line feeds?  Cosmic rays?  Voices inside your head?

Comment: Try this: http://pastebin.com/PZdwWSzt

Answer (score 1):

`comm` is good for this, but it requires the input files to be sorted. If that's not a problem:

```
# lines in FILE_A that are not in FILE_B
comm -23 <(sort FILE_A) <(sort FILE_B)
```

Comment: i checked it and it is working

Answer (score 0):

This script works but does not print what you want. For each filename in FILE_A it prints all the OTHER filenames in FILE_B. Instead you should print the filename yourself if grep does not find it:

```
while read line
do
  grep "$line" FILE_B >/dev/null || echo "$line"
done <FILE_A
```

Comment: grep should also add -w parameter to check full file names instead of just blind text searching...right?

Comment: If each line is a pure filename, it does not make any difference.

Comment: yes as u said it used to do the same, u can try above solution that i have verified

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    if grep -qw $line "file_B"
    then
    echo $line
    fi
done < file_A
```

Comment: It prints the file name which are present in FILE_B
I need to print only all those file names which are not present in FILE_B. your ans needs some modifications. Please reply.

Comment: It prints the file name which are present in FILE_B I need to print only all those file names which are not present in FILE_B. your ans needs some modifications. Please reply.